# 3D Flip Cards are not rotating on tap on Iphone

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I am using the following codepen in wordpress. Ideally, on mobile devices I would like the card to automatically hover when in full view on the device, if that is too complicated a tap works too. Sure beats being here >.< lol

I found a couple threads that were related but none of them worked - ive copied the threads and codepen below.

[-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664255/webkit-transform-style-preserve-3d-not-working)

[CSS flip-animation not working in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834349/css-flip-animation-not-working-in-safari)

Thank you for the help, I wouldn't know what to do at times if this forum wasn't available. I sure don't like hiring a mentor from code-mentor ;/

https://codepen.io/Sourpatchjunkie/pen/BxMVLo

```
  .square-container p {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}       

.square-flip{
        -webkit-perspective: 1000;
        -moz-perspective: 1000;
        -ms-perspective: 1000;
        perspective: 1000;

        -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px);
        -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
        -ms-transform: perspective(1000px);
        transform: perspective(1000px);

        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
        -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
        -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
        transform-style: preserve-3d; 

    /*border:1px solid #efefef;*/

    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:20px;

    }
    .square-flip{
        width:400px;
        height:400px;
    }
    .square,.square2 {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    .square{
        background-size: cover;
        background-position:center center;

        -ms-transition: transform 0.60s cubic-bezier(.5,.3,.3,1);
            transition: transform 0.60s cubic-bezier(.5,.3,.3,1);
            -webkit-transition: transform 0.60s cubic-bezier(.5,.3,.3,1);
        overflow: hidden;

        position:absolute;
        top:0;


        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
        backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    .square-flip .square{
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        z-index:1;
    }
    .square-flip:hover .square{
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

.square p {
  Position: relative;
  top: 50%;
}
    .square2{

        background-size: cover;
        background-position:center center;

        -ms-transition: transform 0.60s cubic-bezier(.5,.3,.3,1);
            transition: transform 0.60s cubic-bezier(.5,.3,.3,1);
            -webkit-transition: transform 0.60s cubic-bezier(.5,.3,.3,1);
        overflow: hidden;

        position:absolute;
        top:0;

        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
        backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    .square-flip .square2{
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        z-index:1;
    }
    .square-flip:hover .square2{
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

    /*Square content*/
    .square-container{
        padding:40px;
        text-align:center;
        position:relative;
        top:50%;

        -ms-transition: transform 0.60s cubic-bezier(.5,.3,.3,1);
            transition: transform 0.60s cubic-bezier(.5,.3,.3,1);
            -webkit-transition: transform 0.60s cubic-bezier(.5,.3,.3,1);


        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(0px)  scale(1);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(0px)  scale(1);
transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(0px)  scale(1);
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        z-index:2;
    }
    .square-flip:hover .square-container{

        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-650px)  scale(.88);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-650px)  scale(.88);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-650px)  scale(.88);
        transform-style: preserve-3d;

    }

    .square-container2{
        padding:40px;
        text-align:center;
        position:relative;
        top:50%;

        -ms-transition: transform 0.60s cubic-bezier(.5,.3,.3,1);
            transition: transform 0.60s cubic-bezier(.5,.3,.3,1);
            -webkit-transition: transform 0.60s cubic-bezier(.5,.3,.3,1);


        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(650px) translateZ(60px) scale(.88);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(650px) translateZ(60px) scale(.88);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(650px) translateZ(60px) scale(.88);

        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        z-index:2;
    }
    .square-flip:hover .square-container2{

        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(0px) translateZ(0px) scale(1);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(0px) translateZ(0px) scale(1);
        transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(0px) translateZ(0px) scale(1);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }



    /*Style text*/
    .square-flip h2{
        color:white;
        font-family: "Open Sans";
        font-weight:700;
        font-size:22px;
    }
    .square-flip h3{
        color:white;
        font-family: "Open Sans";
        font-weight:500;
        font-size:16px;
        line-height:26px;
    }
    /*Elements*/
    .flip-overlay{
        display:block;
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
    }
    .align-center{
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    .kallyas-button{
        display:block;
        width:160px;
        padding:18px 30px;
        font-family:"Open Sans";
        font-weight:600;
        color:#fff;
        background:#FF2024;
        margin:0 auto;
        border-radius:2px;
        text-decoration:none;
}

.p {
  display: block;
  Width: 100px;
}
            /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffa067+0,ff2959+49,ff2024+100 */
            background: #ffa067; /* Old browsers */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #ffa067 0%, #ff2959 49%, #ff2024 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #ffa067 0%,#ff2959 49%,#ff2024 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
            background: linear-gradient(135deg,  #ffa067 0%,#ff2959 49%,#ff2024 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffa067', endColorstr='#ff2024',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
        }
    /*ADD SHADOWS OPTIONAL*/
    .square-flip .square .boxshadow, .square-flip .square .textshadow, .square-flip .square2 .boxshadow, .square-flip .square2 .textshadow{
        -ms-transition: 0.60s;
            transition: 0.60s;
            -webkit-transition: 0.60s;
    }

    .square-flip .square .boxshadow{
        -webkit-box-shadow: 24px 42px 58px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 24px 42px 58px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        box-shadow: 24px 42px 58px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }
    .square-flip .square .textshadow{
        -webkit-text-shadow: 24px 42px 58px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        -moz-text-shadow: 24px 42px 58px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        text-shadow: 24px 42px 58px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }
    .square-flip:hover .square .boxshadow, .square-flip:hover .square .textshadow{
        -webkit-box-shadow: 240px 42px 58px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
        -moz-box-shadow: 240px 42px 58px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
        box-shadow: 240px 42px 58px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    }


    .square-flip .square2 .boxshadow{
        -webkit-box-shadow: 240px 42px 58px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
        -moz-box-shadow: 240px 42px 58px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
        box-shadow: 240px 42px 58px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    }
    .square-flip .square2 .textshadow{
        -webkit-text-shadow: 240px 42px 58px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
        -moz-text-shadow: 240px 42px 58px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
        text-shadow: 240px 42px 58px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    }
    .square-flip:hover .square2 .boxshadow, .square-flip:hover .square2 .textshadow{
        -webkit-box-shadow: 24px 42px 58px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 24px 42px 58px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        box-shadow: 24px 42px 58px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }


    /*You can delete this style*/
    .centerflipcards{
  display:block;
        width:1330px;
  height:440px;
        text-align:center;
        margin:0 auto;
        margin-top:25px;
    }
.clearfix{clear:both;}
.centerflipcards p{
      font-family:"Open Sans";
      font-size:13px;
      margin-top:10px;
      font-weight:700;
}
```

Comment: Does it work on safari desktop? Does it work on chrome mobile?

Comment: It works on safari desktop. Does not work on Chrome or Safari on iOs

Comment: Did you try [HammerJS](https://hammerjs.github.io/)?

Comment: No i'll try that. Any other recommendations?

Comment: All it took was a cursor declaration >.< silly mistake